# How to enumerate audio devices using NAudio in Windows XP

Tags: .net, naudio

I'm trying to use NAudio to record audio in Windows XP (through a .NET application), however, the MMDeviceEnumerator function seems to be unsupported in Windows XP.  Is there an equivalent function in either NAudio, or something else that can be used to get the list of audio devices and pass the selected device to the NAudio object?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `MMDeviceEnumerator` on Windows XP, as this is part of the core audio API that was introduced with Windows Vista. For Windows XP, you need to use the `WaveIn` class instead from which you can get the device count using `WaveIn.DeviceCount` and find out the device name using `WaveIn.GetCapabilities`